# how to extract session from XPObjectSpace in DevExpress 12.2?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, session, devexpress, xpo

i have the following code:

```
Me.ASPxMenu1.DataSource = New HierarchicalMenuItemCollection(New XPCollection(Of IMenuItem)(DirectCast(WebApplication.Instance.ObjectSpaceProvider.CreateObjectSpace(), XPObjectSpace).session,
                                               CType(New NullOperator("ParentItem"), CriteriaOperator),
                                               New SortProperty("Order", DB.SortingDirection.Ascending)))
```

it fails in DirectCast,
in DevExpress 11.2 it was

```
Ctype(WebApplication.Instance.ObjectSpaceProvider.CreateObjectSpace(), ObjectSpace).Session
```

Somebody knows how to do it in DevExpress 12.2?
Thanks for any kind of help

Comment: Why do not you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering own question:

The right method is

```
Dim xpObjectSpaceProvider As New XPObjectSpaceProvider(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("ConnectionString").ConnectionString, Nothing)
Dim ObjectSpace As IObjectSpace = xpObjectSpaceProvider.CreateObjectSpace()

Me.ASPxMenu1.DataSource = New HierarchicalMenuItemCollection(New XPCollection(Of IMenuItem)(CType(ObjectSpace, XPObjectSpace).Session,
                                               CType(New NullOperator("ParentItem"), CriteriaOperator),
                                               New SortProperty("Order", DB.SortingDirection.Ascending)))
```